# Asp.net trying to remove code

Tags: asp.net

I try to remove

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonProfile" runat="server" Checked="true"
            onClick="OnUpdateTypeChange()" GroupName="1" /></td>

            <td>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonPWD" runat="server"
            onClick="OnUpdateTypeChange()" GroupName="1"/></td>

            </tr>
            </table>
```

but ever time i try to remove a asp code it comes up with an error

The error : An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. "

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] UpdateProfile.LocalizePage() +1273 UpdateProfile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +514 System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24 System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +131 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427 
Anyone got a tip for fixing the problem?

The page load javascipt

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function OnLoad() 
    {
        OnUpdateTypeChange();  

        if("<%=m_sSuccess%>" != "")
        {
            alert("<%=m_sSuccess%>");
            window.close();
        }
    }

    function OnUpdateTypeChange() 
    {
        if (document.getElementById("RadioButtonPWD").checked == true) 
        {
            document.getElementById("TableData").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("TablePWD").style.display = "inline";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("RadioButtonProfile").checked == true) 
        {
            document.getElementById("TableData").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("TablePWD").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP. You should retag for ASP.NET. Also, please don't post your error in a comment - edit your original post and put it in there.

Comment: @paul Thanks for the edit tip.

Comment: can u share the code of Page_Load method.

Comment: @aguetat here you go =)

Answer (score 0):

When you delete, for example, the radiobutton "RadioButtonPWD", the function `document.getElementById("RadioButtonPWD")` will return null.

To Correct this, you must make a test :

```
 if (document.getElementById("RadioButtonPWD") != null) {
              if (document.getElementById("RadioButtonPWD").checked == true) {
                  document.getElementById("TableData").style.display = "none";
                  document.getElementById("TablePWD").style.display = "inline";
              }
          }
```

Comment: Hey @aguetat when i remove the code and add the code. It comes up with an error "  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. "

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   UpdateProfile.LocalizePage() +1375
   UpdateProfile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +514
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427

Comment: can u share the code of Page_Load (you find this in YourASPXPage.aspx.cs)

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Determine the sections to render
                if (HasPassword(manager))
                {
                    changePasswordHolder.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    setPassword.Visible = true;
                    changePasswordHolder.Visible = false;
                }

                // Render success message
                var message = Request.QueryString["m"];
                if (message != null)
                {
                    // Strip the query string from action
                    Form.Action = ResolveUrl("~/Account/Manage");
```